# Какими технологии пользоваться для установки будильника на Swift для iOS

Tags: ios, swift, аудио, уведомления, background-task

Я делаю приложение будильника. Так выглядит моя вьюха:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что уже работает:**

Я нажал на кнопку «6:00» одиночным тапом, сработала моя функция `addAlarm("6:00", "unstable")`. Кнопка «6:00» стала выделена зелёным. Само время было запомнено в моделе данных приложения, чтобы кнопка с соответствующим временем осталась подсвеченной после закрытия и повторного открытия приложения.

Кнопка «8:00» горит красным, потому что я тапнул на неё дважды и сработала функция `addAlarm("6:00", "stable")`. Информация так же была записана в модель данных.

**Чего я хочу:**

Зелёный цвет кнопки «6:00» значит, что будильник должен сработать один раз в 6 утра, а затем должен деактивироваться, то есть кнопка снова должна стать синей.

Красный цвет кнопки «8:00» значит, что будильник должен срабатывать каждый день в 8 утра, но после этого кнопка должна также оставаться красной.

Под срабатыванием будильника я имею ввиду следующее. На экране устройства появляется уведомление с текстом «Проснись», и начинает играть мелодия. Файл с мелодией длится 20 секунд, но я хочу, чтобы мелодия длилась 3 минуты, постоянно повторяя 20 секундный файл с мелодией.

Будильник должен срабатывать даже когда приложение свёрнуто, телефон находится в спящем режиме или установлен режим «не беспокоить».

**Чего я не понимаю:**

Ну разумеется, как сделать то, чего я хочу :–) Если серьёзно, то мне не ясно какими методами пользоваться. Мне удалось найти следующее.

Можно [использовать NSTimer](http://makeapppie.com/2015/04/24/swift-swift-using-nstimer-to-make-a-timer-or-alarm/), чтобы вызвать какой-то колбэк через назначенное время, но таймеры перестают работать через 10 минут после сворачивания приложения.

Можно и нужно использовать [UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/) для появления уведомления, но мелодия сопровождающая уведомление не может превышать 30 секнуд, также мне не ясно, как мне вызвать мою функцию `removeAlarm(time)` для будильников установленных однократно, если пользователь никак не отреагирует на уведомление, например, не проснётся.

Можно использовать [Background Modes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial).

**В общем, вопрос:**
Какой или какие методы использовать, как их совместить, и вообще в какую сторону капать?

Comment: как в результате сделали, чтобы из спящего режима проигрывалась мелодия ?

Comment: Я забил на этот будильник и свифт, и вообще решил переквалифицироваться из разработчика в менеджера продукта. Такие пироги.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать

> UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

Просто чередовать его несколько раз подряд,т.е. ставить не одну нотификацию а пачку подряд. Причем можно вызвать просто нотификацию со звуком, не выводя ее на экран.

Т.е первую мы можем вывести, а последующие просто проигрывать звук.